# Insert valores da tabelaB na tabelaA se os mesmos não existirem

Tags: sql

Normalmente, quando trabalhamos com um `insert` em tabelaA se baseando no `select` de uma tabelaB, fazemos algo similar a isso:

```
INSERT INTO tabelaA ( column1, column2, someInt, someVarChar )
SELECT  tabelaB.column1, tabelaB.column2, 8, 'some string etc.'
FROM    tabelaB
```

Porém, o meu problema é que eu preciso validar se os dados já não existem na tabelaA, pois se existirem, o `insert` não será feito

Comment: Talvez um `WHERE NOT EXISTS Xyz` ?

Comment: @RafaelWithoeft Poderia por gentileza demonstrar como ficaria a estrutura?

Comment: Achei um exemplo para você, espero que ajude: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3164505/mysql-insert-record-if-not-exists-in-table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Algo assim:

```
INSERT INTO tabelaA (column1, column2, someInt, someVarChar )
SELECT  tabelaB.column1, tabelaB.column2, 8, 'some string etc.'
FROM    tabelaB
WHERE (SELECT count(Id) FROM tabelaA as valida WHERE valida.column1 = tabelaB.column1) < 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Fica assim:

```
INSERT INTO tabelaA ( column1, column2, someInt, someVarChar )
SELECT  tabelaB.column1, tabelaB.column2, 8, 'some string etc.'
FROM    tabelaB
where not exists (select 1 
                  from tabelaA a2
                  where a2.column1 = tabelaB.column1
                  and s2.column2 = tabelaB.column2
                  and ...)
```

Coloquei reticências porque não sei todas as condições, mas basta completar com mais condições (ou simplesmente retirar o `and ...`).

Answer (score 1):

Não especificaste qual o SGBD que estas a usar. No entanto, fica aqui uma alternativa para SQL Server que muitas vezes é mais rápida que as respostas que foram já postadas.

```
MERGE tabelaA AS Target
USING (SELECT column1, column2, someInt, someVarChar FROM tabelaB) AS Source
   ON (Target.column1 = Source.column1 AND Target.column2 = Source.column2 AND (...))
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
    INSERT (column1, column2, someInt, someVarChar)
    VALUES (Source.column1, Source.column2, Source.someInt, Source.someVarChar)
```

Esta forma é também mais flexível caso, no futuro, decidas que precisas de por exemplo, actualizar os registos na tabela de destino caso eles já existam. Isto pode ser feito da seguinte forma:

```
MERGE tabelaA AS Target
USING (SELECT column1, column2, someInt, someVarChar FROM tabelaB) AS Source
   ON (Target.column1 = Source.column1 AND Target.column2 = Source.column2 AND (...))
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
    INSERT (column1, column2, someInt, someVarChar)
    VALUES (Source.column1, Source.column2, Source.someInt, Source.someVarChar)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET Target.column1= Source.column1
```